# Is it possible to remove fields with *RECURSION* when using toArray() in Propel?

Tags: php, propel, propel2

I am using Propel 2. I am hydrating objects through the relations, like so:

```
$return = OrderQuery::create()
    ->joinWith('Customer')
    ->joinWith('Status')
    ->find()
    ->toArray(TableMap::TYPE_PHPNAME, true, [], true);
```

The resulting Array would look something like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "CustomerId": 1,
  "StatusId": 1,
  "Initiated": "2016-01-01T01:01:01+00:00",
  "Customer": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Forname": "Test",
    "Surname": "Smith",
    "Orders": [
      "*RECURSION*"
    ]
  }
  "Status": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "title 1",
    "Priority": 1,
    "Orders": [
      "*RECURSION*"
    ]
  },
}
```

I want to remove the fields where the value is `*RECURSION*`. I tried using the `$alreadyDumpedObjects` (3rd) parameter to `toArray()` but that didn't seem to help. I could also do some form of array walking with `unset()` calls, but I'm hoping there's a better way, maybe with a formatter or something?

For bonus points, I'd quite like to remove the columns which define the foreign key relationship. For instance, `CustomerId` would go, but `Customer` would remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, it seems, appears to be very simple.

If I use a standard `ArrayFormatter` like this:

```
$return = OrderQuery::create()
    ->setFormatter('Propel\Runtime\Formatter\ArrayFormatter');
    ->joinWith('Customer')
    ->joinWith('Status')
    ->find()
    ->toArray();
```

What is returned is an `ArrayCollection` that, when `toArray()` is called on, is exactly the same as my original output apart from the recursion fields are missing.

Note, when getting one result, for instance with `->findPk(1)`, it will return an associative array, so you shouldn't use `->toArray()` explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

**Note for brevity: This answer has some really helpful information, but there *is* a solution, despite this answer saying there isn't.**

---

The *RECURSION* string is pretty much hardcoded in propel (in src/Propel/Generator/Builder/Orm/ObjectBuilder.php):

```
if (isset(\$alreadyDumpedObjects['$objectClassName'][\$this->hashCode()])) {
    return '*RECURSION*';
}
```

I suppose you could override the object builder, but I doubt that's what you are looking for. Thus, the only other viable way is what you did not want to do, looping over the array and using unset. Something like this:

```
$array = StudyQuery::create()
    ->leftJoinWithInstitute()
    ->find()
    ->toArray();

var_dump($array);
echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(cleanupData($array));

/**
 * @param array $array
 *
 * @return array
 */
function cleanupData(array $array)
{
    $relationsFound = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item === ["*RECURSION*"] || $item == "*RECURSION*") {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } elseif (is_array($item)) {
            $array[$key] = cleanupData($item);
            $relationsFound[] = $key;
        }
    }

    foreach ($relationsFound as $relation) {
        $key = $relation . 'Id';
        if (isset($array[$key])) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

This should also filter out the ***Id-fields, if that relation is present (provided the PHPName for the relation matches the column name).

Comment: It appears there *is* a way to do it after all. See any problems with my solution to your knowledge?

Comment: I think you are correct, yes. Yours is the better answer :)

Answer (score 2):

When you call `toArray` method on a Propel ObjectCollection it will call the `toArray` on every item of the collection (the result of the query).
So there are two way to achieve what you're trying to do:
1) Overwrite the `toArray` method in the `Customer` and `Status` model classes or in the `CustomerCollection` and `StatusCollection` ones (a quick&dirty solution since it gets applied every time you use the `toArray` method...).
2) Extend the `ArrayFormatter` class to define a "skip `Customer` and `Status` strategy" in the `format` method and then add it as the formatter to use (with the `setFormatter` method on the collection) only when you need this particular behavior.

Some refs:
http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#using-an-alternative-collection-class

http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#using-an-alternative-formatter

Comment: Thank you, although I don't need to extend the `ArrayFormatter` as it actually appears to work on its own, as I've shown in my own answer. I appreciate you setting me on the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling:

```
unset($return['Customer']['Orders']);
unset($return['Status']['Orders']);
```

Comment: Yeah, when I said about array walking I meant using unset - I'm specified that more explicitly now in my question. But I would still like something better, that I wouldn't have to hard-code to specific columns